# What are the differences among npm, NuGet and Marketplace download options for Typescript?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, npm, nuget

I use VS pro at work and I am 100% typescript (and React and Node...) beginner dev. I am also trying to understand how all these things work together, why I'd need a given tool etc, not just copying CLI commands and code lines into files.

[Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/releases) I found there are 3 different sources to download typescript: [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript), [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild/3.3.1) and [VS Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TypeScriptTeam.typescript-331-vs2017).

My guess is npm and NuGet are [the same thing just published to different repos](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-3/) but the bits from the Marketplace are always mandatory. Is that correct?

If not, what are the differences among them? I am confused.

Comment: Have a look at the [TypeScript release](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/releases) page. The latest version (TypeScript 3.3.3333) can be downloaded using the sources you mentioned.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT It was very helpful in fact, thanks a lot. It was fast!! I now understand that (and why) I have to install only one of those packages to use Typescript in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are the differences among npm, NuGet and Marketplace download options for Typescript?

What you understand is correct. npm and nuget are two tools for managing libraries. TypeScript provides source for two different tools. Just like you said, they are in the different repos and the way to get them is different also (one is via npm and another is nuget).

For the VS Marketplace, This is another way to get the TypeScript, integrating the TypeScript into the Visual Studio through Visual Studio extension, which has nothing to do with the way of managing the libraries.

So, What you understand is correct.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just to be clear - does that mean there are features in Marketplace that will make TypeScript interact better with Visual Studio IDE in a way that matters to me as developer ? Or does it not matter at all, and using nuget is the better solution, as it ensures the correct version of typescript is always installed, even when the user in question has no admin rights ?